# Вычислить общую сумму игрек линейного графика

Tags: c#, график, логика, syncfusion

График построен на `Syncfusion`,

сам график

```
<SfChart Title="Olympic Medals">
    <ChartPrimaryXAxis ValueType="Syncfusion.Blazor.Charts.ValueType.Category"></ChartPrimaryXAxis>

    <ChartSeriesCollection>
        <ChartSeries DataSource="@MedalDetails" XName="X" YName="Y" Type="ChartSeriesType.Line">
        </ChartSeries>
    </ChartSeriesCollection>
</SfChart>
```

данные

```
public List<ChartData> MedalDetails = new List<ChartData>
{
    new ChartData { X= "02/05/2023", Y= 1 },
    new ChartData { X= "02/05/2023", Y= 2 },
    new ChartData { X= "02/05/2023", Y= 3 },
    new ChartData { X= "02/05/2023", Y= 5 },
    new ChartData { X= "02/05/2023", Y= 8 },
    new ChartData { X= "02/05/2023", Y= 7 },
    new ChartData { X= "02/05/2023", Y= 6 },
    new ChartData { X= "02/05/2023", Y= 11 },
    new ChartData { X= "02/05/2023", Y= 7 },
    new ChartData { X= "02/05/2023", Y= 12 },
    new ChartData { X= "02/05/2023", Y= 2 },
    new ChartData { X= "02/05/2023", Y= 14 },
    new ChartData { X= "02/05/2023", Y= 6 },
    new ChartData { X= "02/05/2023", Y= 12 },
    new ChartData { X= "02/05/2023", Y= 4 },
    new ChartData { X= "02/05/2023", Y= 20 },
    new ChartData { X= "02/05/2023", Y= 10 },
    new ChartData { X= "02/05/2023", Y= 22 },
    new ChartData { X= "02/05/2023", Y= 4 },
    new ChartData { X= "02/05/2023", Y= 1 },
    new ChartData { X= "02/05/2023", Y= 1 },
    new ChartData { X= "02/05/2023", Y= 3 },
    new ChartData { X= "03/05/2023", Y= 1 },
    new ChartData { X= "03/05/2023", Y= 3 },
    new ChartData { X= "03/05/2023", Y= 4 },
    new ChartData { X= "03/05/2023", Y= 9 },
    new ChartData { X= "03/05/2023", Y= 15 },
    new ChartData { X= "03/05/2023", Y= 5 },
    new ChartData { X= "03/05/2023", Y= 23 },
    new ChartData { X= "03/05/2023", Y= 10 },
    new ChartData { X= "03/05/2023", Y= 12 },
    new ChartData { X= "03/05/2023", Y= 1 },
    new ChartData { X= "03/05/2023", Y= 1 },
    new ChartData { X= "03/05/2023", Y= 8 },
    new ChartData { X= "03/05/2023", Y= 7 },
    new ChartData { X= "03/05/2023", Y= 7 },
    new ChartData { X= "03/05/2023", Y= 11 },
    new ChartData { X= "03/05/2023", Y= 9 },
    new ChartData { X= "04/05/2023", Y= 2 },
    new ChartData { X= "04/05/2023", Y= 3 },
    new ChartData { X= "04/05/2023", Y= 4 },
    new ChartData { X= "04/05/2023", Y= 11 },
    new ChartData { X= "04/05/2023", Y= 11 },
    new ChartData { X= "04/05/2023", Y= 13 },
    new ChartData { X= "04/05/2023", Y= 8 },
    new ChartData { X= "04/05/2023", Y= 16 },
    new ChartData { X= "04/05/2023", Y= 5 },
    new ChartData { X= "04/05/2023", Y= 7 },
    new ChartData { X= "04/05/2023", Y= 9 },
    new ChartData { X= "04/05/2023", Y= 11 },
    new ChartData { X= "04/05/2023", Y= 13 },
    new ChartData { X= "04/05/2023", Y= 4 },
    new ChartData { X= "04/05/2023", Y= 8 },
    new ChartData { X= "04/05/2023", Y= 5 },
    new ChartData { X= "05/05/2023", Y= 1 },
    new ChartData { X= "05/05/2023", Y= 1 },
    new ChartData { X= "05/05/2023", Y= 3 },
    new ChartData { X= "05/05/2023", Y= 4 },
    new ChartData { X= "05/05/2023", Y= 9 },
    new ChartData { X= "05/05/2023", Y= 17 },
    new ChartData { X= "05/05/2023", Y= 5 },
    new ChartData { X= "05/05/2023", Y= 10 },
    new ChartData { X= "05/05/2023", Y= 5 },
    new ChartData { X= "05/05/2023", Y= 12 },
    new ChartData { X= "06/05/2023", Y= 1 },
    new ChartData { X= "06/05/2023", Y= 1 },
    new ChartData { X= "06/05/2023", Y= 3 },
    new ChartData { X= "06/05/2023", Y= 10 },
    new ChartData { X= "06/05/2023", Y= 8 },
    new ChartData { X= "06/05/2023", Y= 13 },
    new ChartData { X= "06/05/2023", Y= 3 },
    new ChartData { X= "06/05/2023", Y= 8 }
};
```

модель

```
public class ChartData
{
    public string X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }

}
```

выход

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

...вопрос больше по логике (линия отображается не корректно, и по моему это из за повторения данных икса(???или), я пошла по своей логике и подумала а как можно создать новый игрек объединив все игреки, если икс равен иксу)

то, что я пыталась сделать ❌необходима помощь (как в тулист вернуть результат)

```
    IEnumerable<ChartData>? chartsStatsListTest;
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        chartsStatsListTest = from chart in MedalDetails
                              group chart by chart.X into totalByDay
                              select new
                              {
                                  X = totalByDay.Key,
                                  Y = totalByDay.Sum(x => x.Y),
                              };
    }
```

если данные суммировать, то график показывает линию похожую на график, а не то, что наверху
(это я вручную суммировала, и икс не повторяла в `ChartData`)

необходимый выход
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `x.Equals(x)` всегда `true` - опечатка?

Comment: ☹️нет, не опечатка. Потому что я вижу так: `02/05/2023`=`02/05/2023` а `02/05/2023` != `03/05/2023`, там что писать валю надо или как проверить

Comment: Там должно быть либо `x.Equals(X)` либо `X.Equals(x)`, я полагаю. В противном случае это условие не имеет никакого смысла. Но даже если так, то все равно исходя из вызова, метод `GetTotalByDay` в 100% случаев вернет `Y`. То есть можно напимать так `public int YTest => Y;` и ничего не поменяется.

Comment: тут раньше можно было проект вставить,или?

Comment: zip 436Ko, для теста

Comment: исправила, использую линкЮ, чтоб создать новый `ChartSeries`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

решить можно переопределив `ChartSeries` source, сгрупировав по идентичной строке икс

```
IEnumerable<ChartData>? chartsStatsListTest;
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    var totalByDayToList = 
                from chart in MedalDetails
                group chart by chart.X into ChartData
                select new ChartData()
                {
                    X = ChartData.Key,
                    Y = ChartData.Sum(x => x.Y),
                };
    chartsStatsListTest = totalByDayToList.ToList();
}
```

и в `DataSource` я передаю сгрупированный список

```
<ChartSeriesCollection>
    <ChartSeries DataSource="chartsStatsListTest" XName="X" YName="Y" Type="ChartSeriesType.Line">
    </ChartSeries>
</ChartSeriesCollection>
```

результат корректно работает, если есть решения как улучшить ?

Comment: что за мода использовать @ перед названием методов?

Comment: [вот когда они используют например привязку параметров](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/aspnet/core/blazor/?view=aspnetcore-7.0) и еще было где то видела в док, и поэтому не всегда понятно где надо, а где нет, оба рабочие, если добавить ЛИШНИЙ РАЗ не убудет, а если не ВСТАВИТЬ КОГДА НАДО, то выдаст ошибку